# Netbeans build adds timestamp to project.properties

Tags: netbeans, build, ant, ivy

I am running a java web app on Netbeans.

Every time I right click on the project and click `Run`, the build process adds a date and time stamp to the top of the `project.properties` file, like this:

```
#Mon, 04 Jun 2018 13:57:02 +0300
```

This is a problem when versioning because it always creates conflicts when `rebase` is called.

How can I remove this from the build so that a time stamp is not printed to this file?

(I'm not sure if this question is related to the dependency management tool `ivy` or not. It is possible that this only started happening once I started using `ivy` and that's why it's tagged in this question).

Thanks

Comment: I think Ivy is probably doing that; Netbeans itself definitely does not update **project.properties** with a timestamp every time that a project is run. And although it's an old post, [this Ivy/NetBeans user](http://grokbase.com/t/ant/ivy-user/1028q9wytz/integrating-ivy-with-netbeans) is also complaining that _"my project.properties keeps on changing. I have to commit or revert it after every build"_.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into it and report back.

Comment: The only solution I saw there that seemed relevant was the one suggesting that I simply ignore project.properties when versioning, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: OK, I agree that ignoring **project.properties** doesn't seem like a good approach. If you could do a one-time copy of **project.properties** to (say) **projectForIvy.properties**, and then somehow configure that file to Ivy as the property file to be used instead, that might solve the problem. Ivy is not specific to NetBeans, so it seems pretty unlikely that using a file named **project.properties** is hard-coded (but I don't know Ivy at all so I can't really help any further).